# Python vk_api завести код под бесконечный цикл

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я написал скрипт который не позволяет админу беседы вк исключить юзера,реализовал это тем что когда кикают одного,фейк который зашел до этого и вышел снова приглашает первого ,а сам выходит.В итоге получается так что скрипт выполняет это очень быстро,и подловить и кикнуть фейк почти нереально.Реализовал я это так:

```
import vk_api 
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi("login","password") 
vk_session.auth() 
vk = vk_session.get_api()


main_join=vk.messages.addChatUser(chat_id=13,user_id=id1)
if main_join==1:
    print("Успешный вход")
else:
    print("Вход не удался")


join_user=vk.messages.addChatUser(chat_id=13,user_id=id2)
if join_user==1:
    print("Успешное добавление")
else:
    print("Добавление не удалось")

remove_user=vk.messages.removeChatUser(chat_id=13,user_id=id1)
if remove_user==1:
    print("Успешный выход")
else:
    print("Выход не удался")
```

Но получается что мне нужно каждый раз запускать чтобы вернуться в беседу.Tак как это все сделать,чтобы я мог запустить единожды и скрипт сам мог определять когда меня кикают.

Comment: бесконечный цикл -- `while True:`

Comment: это понятно но у меня проблема в том что как опознать находится ли пользователь в беседе,в документации ничего не нашел толком,может есть кто работал с вк апи документацией

Comment: Получите список пользователей беседы, проверьте, есть ли там нужный пользователь. И все тут (с VK API уже года 2 дел не имел, как и с питоном - берегу нервную систему - так что дать пример не могу)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov а там нельзя чекнуть состояние юзеров беседы на странице где ты вышел с беседы,конкретнее не могу сделать запрос т.к не нахожусь в беседе.Получается надо делать запрос со страницы которую кикают и которую приглашают.

Comment: Это вполне логично (хотя ВК часто с логикой не дружит): было бы странно, если бы Вы могли узнавать данные из чужих закрытых бесед. Так что да, мониторьте этот вопрос, используя аккаунт, что ещё точно находится в беседе

Comment: @Kir_Antipov вполне хорошая идея но у меня проблема с реализацией,как можно авторизоваться с еще одного аккаунта,чтобы использовать его сессию,у меня выдает ошибку

Comment: Думаю, это повод для нового вопроса. Я не знаю деталей реализации используемой Вами библиотеки, так что тут помочь ничем не могу. Вообще, так как у Вас весьма скромный функционал - можете реализовать отправку запросов ручками. Аккаунты у Вас, я так понимаю, одни и те же, так что можете вручную получить бесконечные токены и далее самостоятельно лепить их в запросы